# How to execute a file after compilation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to execute the file that is a result of a successful compilation, but I have no idea how to do so.

What I know is the full path of the file, so I need to run a command like double click on the file after compilation.. any idea?

Comment: Are you compiling via vscode tasks? can you post your .vscode/tasks.json?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you should be able to do that with appropriate [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Of course, the concrete implementation depends on the kind of task runner you will use but e.g. with gulp you could use [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to execute your compilation / build result after the build (gulp) task is done

Comment: it seems easier to launch the file manually than to learn gulp thing